# Google Translate Icon Enable in URL

Tags: google-translation-api

I want to enable Google Translate icon and list language in url near to bookmark, but i already used google translate api, and i don't want to install translate extension. Please see image as references...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g2oW.png)
Thanks in advance !!

function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en',layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.INLINE, }, 'google_translate_element');
}

I used above script.